# Automapper enum to Enumeration Class

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

I'm trying to use Automapper to map from a regular enum to an Enumeration Class (as described by Jimmy Bogard - http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/).  The regular enum doesn't have the same values as the enumeration class does. I would therefore like to map using the Name if possible:

Enum:

```
public enum ProductType
{
    ProductType1,
    ProductType2
}
```

Enumeration Class:

```
public class ProductType : Enumeration
{
    public static ProductType ProductType1 = new ProductType(8, "Product Type 1");
    public static ProductType ProductType2 = new ProductType(72, "Product Type 2");

    public ProductType(int value, string displayName)
        : base(value, displayName)
    {
    }

    public ProductType()
    {
    }
}
```

Any help to make this mapping work appreciated!  I have attempted just a regular mapping:

```
Mapper.Map<ProductType, Domain.ProductType>();
```

.. but the mapped type has a value of 0.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Some feedback on the negative vote would be great whoever you are, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how Automapper works - it gets public *instance* properties/fields of destination type, and matches the with public *instance* properties/fields of source type. Your enum does not have public properties. Enumeration class has two - Value and DisplayName. There is nothing to map for Automapper. Best thing you can use is simple mapper function (I like to use extension methods for that):

```
public static Domain.ProductType ToDomainProductType(
    this ProductType productType)
{
    switch (productType)
    {
        case ProductType.ProductType1:
            return Domain.ProductType.ProductType1;
        case ProductType.ProductType2:
            return Domain.ProductType.ProductType2;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ProductType productType = ProductType.ProductType1;
var result = productType.ToDomainProductType();
```

If you really want to use Automapper in this case, you ca provide this creation method to `ConstructUsing` method of mapping expression:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductType, Domain.ProductType>()
      .ConstructUsing(Extensions.ToDomainProductType);
```

You also can move this creation method to `Domain.ProductType` class. Then creating its instance from given enum value will look like:

```
var result = Domain.ProductType.Create(productType);
```

---

UPDATE: You can use reflection to create generic method which maps between enums and appropriate enumeration class:

```
public static TEnumeration ToEnumeration<TEnum, TEnumeration>(this TEnum value)
{
    string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(TEnum), value);
    var field = typeof(TEnumeration).GetField(name);
    return (TEnumeration)field.GetValue(null);
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = productType.ToEnumeration<ProductType, Domain.ProductType>();
```

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation, I understand the problem now. I think I'll probably end up changing the enum to have matching values, and map to the Value instance member of the Enumeration Class. I was more curious than anything else! I think the reflection version is fairly nice, so may come in handy at some point. Thanks

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing - if you did want to map from an enum with the same value as the enumeration class (a different question I know)

mapper.CreateMap<ProductType, Domain.ProductType>()
                .ConstructUsing(dto => Enumeration.FromValue<Domain.ProductType>((int)dto.SourceValue));