# Automapper unable to project one enum type to another

Tags: linq, automapper

I'm leveraging the Project functionality in Automapper and Entity Framework, but I'm running into an issue where Automapper doesn't seem to want to project one enum type to another.

I have the following entities:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private HashSet<UserProfilePhone> m_Phones;
    public virtual HashSet<UserProfilePhone> Phones
    {
        get { return m_Phones ?? (m_Phones = new HashSet<UserProfilePhone>()); }
        set { this.m_Phones = value; }
    }
}

public class UserProfilePhone
{
    public PhoneType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
}

public enum PhoneType
{
    Home = 1,
    Work = 2,
    Mobile = 3,
    Other = 4
}
```

I then am projecting these types to the following models:

```
public class UserProfileModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserProfilePhoneModel> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfilePhoneModel
{
    public UserProfilePhoneTypeModel Type { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }        
}

public enum UserProfilePhoneTypeModel
{
    Home = 1,
    Work = 2,
    Mobile = 3,
    Other = 4
}
```

I then setup my mappings like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PhoneType, UserProfilePhoneTypeModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UserProfilePhone, UserProfilePhoneModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<UserProfile, UserProfileModel>();
```

And finally I'm executing my projection:

```
var result = dbContext.UserProfiles.Project().To<UserProfileModel>();
```

When I do this, I get the following exception:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Unable to create a map expression from MyNamespace.PhoneType to
>   MyNamespace.Models.UserProfilePhoneTypeModel
>       Unable to create a map expression from MyNamespace.PhoneType to MyNamespace.Models.UserProfilePhoneTypeModel
>       Result StackTrace:
>       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>       ...

I've tried creating explicit mappings, but they appear to be ignored. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automapper enum to Enumeration Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453398/automapper-enum-to-enumeration-class)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As usual, I figured out the answer almost as soon as I posted the question.

Modifying the create map line to provide an explicit cast did the trick:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserProfilePhone, UserProfilePhoneModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(t => (UserProfilePhoneTypeModel)t.Type));
```

Comment: Mapping works without projection, but fails when you try to project one enum to another. Is is a Automapper bug?

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug.

Comment: Ran into the same issue (mapping works when not using projection). The biggest issue for us is that AuoMapper doesn't throw an exception when calling `AssertConfigurationIsValid` method

Comment: Turns out there is a BIG distinction between what `Map` does vs what `ProjectTo` does, see here for reference: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/840